# PHP - submit fields from another form when submitting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

With jquery I hide and show the divs shown below when I need to.
When submitting into the div.preview I need php to take fields only from the form-container.

I tried to make the whole main-container a form but then I would change all the css rules for that webpage.

Is that possible?

My html structure is something like this:

```
div.main-container
    div.notes1 (hidden)
    div.notes2 (hidden)
    div.preview (hidden)
         button submit
    div.form-container (displayed)
        field1
        field2
        field3
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] here using the stack snippet: `<>` in the editor.

Comment: so preview has fields too?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to jQuery:

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" name="input1" value="Input I" >
    <input type="text" name="input2" value="Input II" >
</form>
<div id="preview">
    Submit the form.
</div>

<script>
  $("#preview").click(function() {
    $("#form").submit();
  });
</script>
```